# if the probability a shooter hits the target is equal to .8 then ...?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

if the probability a shooter hits the target is equal to .8 then the probability that the shooter will correctly hit the target after 10 failed attempt is equal ......?

probability of hitting the target after 10 is the same as 1 - the probability of failing 10 times

so P=1-(1-.8)^10 
    =0.9999999989

is the answer correct !

Comment: No.  The probability of hitting the target after ten misses is the same as if it were after ten hits: $0.8$.

Comment: For the record, "1 - the probability of failing 10 times (in 10 shots)" gives you the probability of the opposite event, that is to say: "*the probability of hitting* **at least once** *in 10 shots*"

Answer (score 2):

The probability that he hits the target on this 11th attempt is $0.8$ - you're assuming that past (independent, we assume) events have an effect on the outcome of the event.

On the other hand, the probability of that specific **sequence** of events, $10$ failures and $1$ success, is $$(0.2)^{10}(0.8) = 8.2\times10^{-8}$$

Comment: could you explain more how did you solve it ,,, I don't understand why you multiply .2^10 by -8

Comment: The 0.2^10 is the first 10 misses, but then you also need to account for the fact that the last shot hit, which has a 0.8 probability.